# sizeof(value) vs sizeof(type)?

Tags: c++, runtime, sizeof, compile-time

Considering :

```
double data; 
double array[10]; 
std::vector<int> vec(4, 100); 
MyClass myclass;
```

Is there a difference between :

```
sizeof(double);
sizeof(double[10]);
sizeof(std::vector<int>);
sizeof(MyClass);
```

and

```
sizeof(data);
sizeof(array);
sizeof(vec);
sizeof(myclass);
```

Are the two syntaxes different or strictly equivalent ? Are all of them evaluated at compile-time ? If not, which one is evaluated at run-time ?

Comment: The size of a type can't change at runtime. `sizeof` always yields its value at compile-time.

Comment: Not really relevant, since you're asking about C++; But the only time `sizeof` is evaluated at runtime, as far as I know, is in C, with variable length arrays.  But those aren't legal in C++, though they are allowed with GCC as an extension.

Comment: I know that the result is the same, my question is : is there any difference in the assembly code ?

Comment: Also note that with `sizeof(std::vector<int>);` this will not change no matter the number of the elements contained

Comment: Assembly code? Since it's resolved at compile time the result is a size_t value, I don't think it could change assembly at all.

Comment: No, there is no difference.  By definition the size of the variable is the size of its type.  When someone less lazy quotes chapter and verse of the spec, accept their answer

Comment: @Vincent You can check this yourself. Write a very small program and compile it with the -S flag (for GCC). It'll give you a .s file with the assembly output.

Comment: Thanks ! I just checked that and the assembly code is the same !

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The only differences are in syntax and convenience.

Syntactically, you're allowed to leave out the parentheses in one case, but not the other:

```
double d;

sizeof(double); // compiles
sizeof(d);      // compiles
sizeof d;       // compiles
sizeof double;  // does NOT compile
```

As far as convenience goes, consider something like:

```
float a;

x = sizeof(float);

y = sizeof(a);
```

If, for example, you sometime end up changing `a` from a `float` to a double, you'd also need to change `sizeof(float)` to `sizeof(double)` to match. If you use `sizeof(a)` throughout, when you change `a` from a `float` to a `double`, all your uses of `sizeof` will automatically change too, without any editing. The latter is more often a problem in C than C++, such as when calling malloc:

```
float *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(float));
```

vs.

```
float *a = malloc(10 * sizeof(*a));
```

In the first case, changing the first `float` to `double` will produce code that compiles, but has a buffer overrun. In the second case, changing the (only) `float` to `double` works fine.

Comment: It's also neat to note that the Linux kernel code guidelines cover this, suggesting to use sizeof(*variable) for determining the struct size of a pointer-to-struct. It's probably a good idea to do that, if you end up in such a situation (though in C++ it should be rare.)

Answer (score 2):

The latter is defined in terms of the former.  Given an expression, it returns the size of the type of the expression. So `sizeof(vec)` translates to `sizeof(std::vector<int>)`.

Both are evaluated at compile-time; the only run-time `sizeof` is in C, not C++, with variable-length arrays. The operand to `sizeof` is unevaluated, so there isn't any real possibly the expression itself could generate code anyway.

I prefer to use expressions over types, because chances are stating the type is redundant in some fashion.

Comment: I prefer expression as well. Because they make mainenance easier. If you change the type of a variable you only need to change it in one place rather than track down how the type is used (ie in sizeof()).

Comment: @LokiAstari: Yup, it matches better conceptually as well: why deduce the type and size that? We want the size of the expression so type it!

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use `sizeof(<whatever>)`, it is always evaluated at compile time. It is the datatype of the parameter that `sizeof` is concerned with.

However, you can pass values, and even expressions as parameter. But the sizeof function will only consider the dataype of the passed parameter.

You can also pass expressions as `sizeof(x = x+1);`. Say `x` was int. In this case this `sizeof` will return `4`(as on my machine) and the value of x will remain unchanged. This is because `sizeof` is always evaluated at compile time.

The two set of syntax you provide, will return the same result, but you cannot say they are equivalent. But yes, latter is defined in terms of former.